# Vagrantfile packaged in box (via packer) is not used

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, packer

I used [packer](/questions/tagged/packer) to create a [vagrant](/questions/tagged/vagrant) box for a workshop I am running, and packaged [vagrantfile](/questions/tagged/vagrantfile) in the box via the `vagrantfile_template` directive in the Vagrant post-processor as shown:

```
...
"post-processors": [{
  "type": "vagrant",
  "vagrantfile_template": "vagrantfile_templates/workshop",
  "compression_level": "{{user `compression_level`}}",
  "output": "fedora-22-x86_64.box"
}],
...
```

The contents of the resulting `.box` are:

```
% tar -tf workshop.box
Vagrantfile
box.ovf
metadata.json
packer-fedora-22-x86_64-disk1.vmdk
```

The contents of `Vagrantfile` in the box seem OK, and include the contents of the `vagrantfile_template` specified in the packer configuration.  Note that this `Vagrantfile` defines two VMs named `client` and `server`:

```
% tar -O -xf freeipa-workshop.box Vagrantfile

# The contents below were provided by the Packer Vagrant post-processor

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.base_mac = "0800278AF3E8"
end


# The contents below (if any) are custom contents provided by the
# Packer template during image build.
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "workshop"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

  config.vm.define "server" do |server|
    server.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    server.vm.hostname = "server.ipademo.local"
  end

  config.vm.define "client" do |client|
    client.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.20"
    client.vm.hostname = "client.ipademo.local"
  end

end
```

I added the box to vagrant with the name `workshop`:

```
% vagrant box add --name workshop workshop.box 
==> box: Adding box 'workshop' (v0) for provider: 
    box: Downloading: file:///.../workshop.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'workshop' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
% vagrant box list
workshop                  (virtualbox, 0)
```

### Problem description

When I execute `vagrant init workshop` and then `vagrant up`, the `Vagrantfile` included in the box is not applied:

```
% vagrant init workshop
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
% cat Vagrantfile 
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "workshop"

  ... and so on (the rest of the default Vagrantfile)

% vagrant up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
...
```

Whoa! Why did it bring up `default`?  [According to the `Vagrantfile` docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/index.html) the Vagrantfile packaged with the box should be used, and other `Vagrantfile`s including from the current directory should be *merged into it*.  But this does not seem to be the case.

Vagrant **1.7.2** is the version in use.

I would like workshop participants to be able to bring up the VMs defined in the `Vagrantfile` included in the box, without supplying that `Vagrantfile` out of band (in order to minimise dependencies).  Have I missed something important?

Comment: Is your `/vagrant` folder disabled too so it has been ignored from the template ? or only the multi machine part has been ignored ? do you really have `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|` twice in the Vagrantfile can you try to merge into one

Answer (score 0):

As all of us know, Vagrant loads and merges multiple Vagrantfiles in a pre-determined order outlined [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/#load-order-and-merging) (in the same section they also point out that multiple `Vagrant.configure` blocks are also OK).

I was experiencing the same very same issue when Vagrant would not pick up the `config.vm.communicator = "winrm"` configuration that was bundled in the .box using `vagrantfile_template`.

However, by Using `vagrant --debug` I noticed that Vagrant appeared to have cached the bundled Vagrantfile from a previous build of the same box:

```
INFO loader: Set :"26224240_win7sp1_x64_virtualbox" = ["#<Pathname:/home/thomas/.vagrant.d/boxes/win7sp1_x64/0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile>"]
```

One would think that `vagrant destroy` would remove the associated files in `vagrant.d` but it does not, so I was able to resolve the issue by manually removing `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/win7sp1_x64`.

I confirmed that it now was working as intended by seeing that WinRM was indeed being used:

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: WinRM address: 127.0.0.1:55985
    default: WinRM username: vagrant
    default: WinRM execution_time_limit: PT2H
    default: WinRM transport: negotiate
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
```

Even though the Vagrantfile in the initialized directory did not have that configuration:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "win7sp1_x64"
    config.vm.box_url = "/media/data/VagrantBaseBoxes/win7sp1_x64/win7sp1_x64-virtualbox.box"
end
```

**TL;DR:**

Make sure no "old" Vagrantfiles are present in `vagrant.d` that may overwrite what's configured in the '`packer`-ed box (see "load order and merging" in the link above).

Comment: Also, I noticed some issues when testing inside a subdir of a location that contained a Vagrantfile. My advice would be to test in a subdir of /tmp to avoid any such trouble